# Authentication Angular 8 client with Azure AD

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, active-directory

I use the blog https://www.digital-moves.eu/2018/07/19/authentication-with-azure-ad-angular-6-client-web-api/  to authenticate angular-8 application with Azure AD application.

If lunch app in local host Azure login page is displaying and after entering credentials the angular-8 app works fine.
But after deployment angular app after login in Azure login page displays error message: “The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.” Chrome development tools window shows the status code 404 for request “https://my_app.azurewebsites.net/auth-callback”.

Below are Azure AD application settings:
Return (redirect) URIs: https://my_app.azurewebsites.net/auth-callback, http://localhost:4200/auth-callback.
ID tokens is selected in implicit grant section.
Logout url is https://my_app.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Could you show you have configured authentication in your front-end?

Comment: AppComponent class in angular app includes     
private adalConfig = {
        tenant: 'tenant_id',
        clientId: 'client_id_Azure_AD_App_Id,
        redirectUri:  environment.clientBaseUrl + '/auth-callback',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.clientBaseUrl,
        endpoints: {
            'https://my-web-api.azurewebsites.net':  'objectId'
        }
    }

where clientBaseUrl  is either "http://localhost:4200 or https://my_app.azurewebsites.net